# Using hex as delimitor when splitting string

Tags: c#, string

I am reading a string of a socket. The sting contains key-value pairs using the hex 0x01 as delimitor. I would like to split the string to get the pairs, but can't quite get my head around it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

.NET/C#. Framework 4.

Comment: “You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means.” `hex` is the way you express a value, not the value itself.  If you have 127 dollars, you have hex 0x7F dollars, but the same amount of money.  The delimiter you are talking about is ^A, which, in hex *as in every base*, is character 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given a string `input`, you can split it using the `Split` method:

```
string[] splitted = input.Split(new char[] { (char)0x01});
```

You might want to use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` as well to remove any elements not containing any readable char.

Comment: Yes, thanks for this answer.  I was trying to figure out how to use some escape sequence to do it!  blech!